# CSRF token is null on file upload- spring mvc

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, csrf, csrf-protection

I am uploading a file. The jsp has the following.

```
 <form id="uploadRepoData" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input style="width: 250px" type="file" name="loadfile" class="loadInputDisplay"/>
```

On clicking the submit button, the csrf token is appended to the form and a post request is done.
However, the request seems to have a null csrf token, hence the request is thought to be an invalid request and
it fails.

I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Could you please share the spring security configuration?

Answer (score 1):

By appending the csrf token as a query parameter to the action fixed it

Comment: Can you clarify how exactly you did that?

Answer (score -2):

Append csfr in your form action......

```
<s:form  action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/marketinfo/bulkupload?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}" 
   enctype="multipart/form-data" modelAttribute="upload" method="POST" 
   class="form-horizontal" role="form">
```